# What is the difference between tracking and mapping (TAM) and localization and mapping (LAM)?

Tags: computer-vision, comparison, terminology, papers, slam

In the paper [Visual SLAM algorithms: a survey from 2010 to 2016](https://ipsjcva.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s41074-017-0027-2) by Takafumi Taketomi, Hideaki Uchiyama and Sei Ikeda it is mentioned

> It should be noted that tracking and mapping (TAM) is used instead of using localization and mapping. TAM was first used in Parallel Tracking and Mapping (PTAM) [15] because localization and mapping are not simultaneously performed in a traditional way. Tracking is performed in every frame with one thread whereas mapping is performed at a certain timing with another thread. After PTAM was proposed, most of vSLAM algorithms follows the framework of TAM. Therefore, TAM is used in this paper.

I do not quite follow the difference between localization and mapping versus tracking and mapping.

1. What is the difference?
2. What are some advantages of TAM?
3. Why is SLAM not called STAM?